# how to count of model of car

Tags: sql

**Person Table**

```
ID FirstName  LastName PersonalWealth
1  Hello      Alest    $10,000.00
2  Leeds      United   $20,000.00
3  Middle     Brough   $30,000.00
4  Arsenal    Chelsey  $40,000.00
5  Manchester United   $50,000.00
6  Peter      Mean     $60,000.00
7  Hello      Coward   $60,000.00
```

**Car Table**

```
ID  CarRego  Model   Make   Manufacture  Year PersonID
1   abc123   Van            Toyota       2001 1
2   abc234   Ute            Honda        2005 1
3   pio345   Hatchback      Mitsubishi   1990 2
4   elf234   Hatchback      Ford         1996 3
5   flo124   Hatchback      Toyota       1992 4
6   asc234   hatchback      Holden       1965 6
7   xyz      hatchback      Holden       1998 5
8   avc      Van            jhjhjkhk     1989 1
```

**Here is the SQL code that i have**

```
SELECT
  Count(Car.ID) AS CountOfid1, 
  Car.Model
FROM person
INNER JOIN Car ON person.ID=Car.ID
GROUP BY Car.Model;
```

But it works with van saying 2 of them but in real there is only one owner how do i fix this?

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: It would really help if you include both all of yuor schemas.  Saying you're getting two `van`s doesn't help if we can't see the table.

Comment: `person.ID=Car.ID` should be either `person.CarID=Car.ID` or `person.ID=Car.PersonID` ?

Comment: OK - what database system and version are you using?? Also: if you reference a "Car" table - can you show us what that table looks like (structure: fields and datatypes - and sample data) ? OTherwise we're left guessing at best......

Comment: Can you add the details for your Car table as well?

Comment: No one can help if you don't provide all the details entitled in the problem.

Comment: Why are you joining to the PERSON table if all you want is a count of the models?

Comment: What is the difference between the Make and the Manufacturer columns? Also, the person with id 1 owns the vehicles with IDs 1, 2 and 8 - two of them vans. I'm not sure what your problem is with it returning two vans as userID 1 owns both those vans. Can you explain the requirements better? I agree with the people pointing out a problem with the join.

Comment: Can you supply desired results then we can probably work out what you need from there!

Answer (score 1):

Youl have to be a little more clear in your question ,im not sure what you want to achieve! if there is one owner per car then maybe setting the PK of car to owner then you ensure only own owner/car. That way you will never have dupe owners cos the pk will clash and youl get a PK exception if you try to add.

Comment: here is the database for car 
ID CarRego Model   Make ManufactureYear PersonID
1 abc123 Van  Toyota 2001 1
2 abc234 Ute  Honda 2005 1
3 pio345 HatchbackMitsubishi1990 2
4 elf234 HatchbackFord 1996 3
5 flo124 HatchbackToyota 1992 4
6 asc234 hatchbackHolden 1965 6
7 xyz hatchbackHolden 1998 5
8 avc Van jhjhjkhk 1989 1

Answer (score 1):

I am having a lot of trouble following this question but i see one clear problem

```
INNER JOIN Car ON person.ID=Car.ID
```

This does not make sense to me.  I think what that line should read is

```
INNER JOIN Car ON person.ID=Car.OwnerID
```

Comparing primary keys to primary keys means nothing

Answer (score -1):

here is the database for car

```
ID  CarRego  Model   Make   Manufacture  Year PersonID
1   abc123   Van            Toyota       2001 1
2   abc234   Ute            Honda        2005 1
3   pio345   Hatchback      Mitsubishi   1990 2
4   elf234   Hatchback      Ford         1996 3
5   flo124   Hatchback      Toyota       1992 4
6   asc234   hatchback      Holden       1965 6
7   xyz      hatchback      Holden       1998 5
8   avc      Van            jhjhjkhk     1989 1
```

Comment: iam trying to find out count of owners of each model of car so doing the count let's say van has one owner so the sql should return 1 but its returning two different person. make and model is different